# Trading View CrossOver Function in Python

Tags: python, tradingview-api

I am looking for a built-in function from trading view (crossover function) and make it happen in python, below is the trading view argument and return value:

The `x`-series is defined as having crossed over `y`-series if the value of `x` is greater than the value of `y` and the value of `x` was less than the value of `y` on the bar immediately preceding the current bar.

```
crossover(x, y) → series[bool]
```

Return:

```
true if `x` crossed over `y` otherwise false
```

Arguments:

```
x (float) Data series `x`.
y (float) Data series `y`.
```

i try to use backtrader API for crossover functions but the function only contain one argument to access data1 and data2 in the same arrays. Below are the functions:

```
class CrossOver(Indicator):
'''
This indicator gives a signal if the provided datas (2) cross up or down.

  - 1.0 if the 1st data crosses the 2nd data upwards
  - -1.0 if the 1st data crosses the 2nd data downwards

It does need to look into the current time index (0) and the previous time
index (-1) of both the 1t and 2nd data

Formula:
  - diff = data - data1
  - upcross =  last_non_zero_diff < 0 and data0(0) > data1(0)
  - downcross = last_non_zero_diff > 0 and data0(0) < data1(0)
  - crossover = upcross - downcross
'''
_mindatas = 2

lines = ('crossover',)

plotinfo = dict(plotymargin=0.05, plotyhlines=[-1.0, 1.0])

def __init__(self):
    upcross = CrossUp(self.data, self.data1)
    downcross = CrossDown(self.data, self.data1)

    self.lines.crossover = upcross - downcross
```

Above function does not meet my requirement as I have 2 series of numpy array which is x and y and x will crossover y which the requirement same as pinescript above.

Or is there any API that I can use for crossover function immediately in Python? I try to search everywhere but cant find the suitable one which only return True or False by comparing argument of x numpy arrays and y numpy arrays.

i try to built myself for crossover function as below:

```
def crossover(x,y):
    j = -len(x)
    while j < 0:
        if x[j] > y[j]:
            return True
        j += 1
```

but i am not sure the criteria from crossover function in pinescript meet my own function condition, i need help for verification.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information regarding your problem.  First what libraries are you using? What have you tried already?  Where are you encountering the problem?  What data structure is your x and y values? Panda Series, numpy array, list, other?  Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Comment: i have edited the post.. please help thanks :)

Comment: Can you provide a short sample of input data for x and y as well as an idea of what result you are looking for?

Comment: yes for sure. i think i got some point from your question and i dont think my own function for crossover is correct. Assume x_array = [3 4 5 6 7] and y_array = [5,6,7,8,9], x_array value will iterate the y_array and if one of the value (5) from x_array is bigger than y_array from any of the value then it means crossover. Correct me if i am wrong. Imagine there are 2 lines in the chart and y_array values is greater than x _array values.. so when the x_array values change followed by the date, and it cross the y_line. my result is looking for the intersect of x series and y series.

Comment: i have edited my own built function for crossover follow by the rules: The x-series is defined as having crossed over y-series if the value of x is greater than the value of y and the value of x was less than the value of y on the bar immediately preceding the current bar. Kindly need your help for verification.

Comment: To edit my input data for x_array and y_array, they should compare parallel instead iterate.